# Copying S3 bucket file to secondary bucket?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

**Issue:** My access is being denied when I run the following AWS Lambda code:

```
require 'json'
require "aws-sdk-s3"

def lambda_handler(event:, context:)
    client = Aws::S3::Client.new(region: 'us-east-2')

    record = event["Records"][0]
    key = record.dig *%w(s3 object key)

    client.copy_object({
      bucket: "bucket-name", 
      copy_source: "#{key}", 
      key: "#{key}", 
    })

end
```

**Error:**

```
"errorType": "Function<Aws::S3::Errors::AccessDenied>",
```

**My IAM role:**

- `AmazonS3FullAccess`: AWS managed policy
- `AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole-e41b74ba-3cef-4470-8f1c-3f900591016c`: Managed policy
- `AWSConfigRulesExecutionRole`

Shouldn't this be good to go?

The purpose of the lambda is to take files uploaded to the bucket and copy them over to another bucket.

Comment: Are both buckets owned by the same AWS Account?

Comment: Yes, I actually just updated it and it works.  Check my answer below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require 'json'
require "aws-sdk-s3"

def lambda_handler(event:, context:)
    client = Aws::S3::Client.new(region: 'us-east-2')

    record = event["Records"][0]
    key = record.dig *%w(s3 object key)

    client.copy_object({
      bucket: "bucket-name", 
      copy_source: "#{key}", 
      key: "#{key}", 
    })

end
```

Needs to be:

```
require 'json'
require "aws-sdk-s3"

    def lambda_handler(event:, context:)
        client = Aws::S3::Client.new(region: 'us-east-2')

        record = event["Records"][0]
        key = record.dig *%w(s3 object key)

        client.copy_object({
          bucket: "bucket-name", 
          copy_source: "/bucketname/#{key}", 
          key: "#{key}", 
        })

    end
```

Must specify the source which is the bucket-name/file-name

Answer (score 0):

Since the code is run in AWS Lambda, your IAM role permissions have no impact on the code execution. Instead Lambda execution role needs to have the S3 permission in this case.

You need to create a new role with required permissions and update Lambda execution role to the newly created role.

Comment: I added  AmazonDMSRedshiftS3Role
AWS managed policy

  AWSLambdaFullAccess
AWS managed policy

  AmazonS3FullAccess
AWS managed policy

  QuickSightAccessForS3StorageManagementAnalyticsReadOnly
AWS managed policy

  AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess
AWS managed policy

AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole-e41b74ba-355-4470-8f1c-3f91134655016c
Managed policy

  AWSConfigRulesExecutionRole

Comment: still not going through!

Comment: What is the execution role for Lambda function? Does that have S3 permission?

Comment: Welcome Jeechu.  @jeechu duka it is the comment above yours.  I even over did the role permissions and it still won't work.  is the code itself fine?

Comment: It's solely the access to the bucket.  If i change the name of the bucket to one that doesn't exist, it lets me know the bucket doesn't exist.  I'm not sure why it won't allow me in.  I have cleared just about everything.

Answer (score 0):

The `copy_object()` command requires:

- Source bucket
- Source key
- Destination bucket
- Destination key

Your code is only referencing one bucket name and is using the same Key.

The documentation shows:

```
resp = client.copy_object({
  bucket: "destinationbucket", 
  copy_source: "/sourcebucket/HappyFace.jpg", 
  key: "HappyFaceCopyjpg", 
})
```

You'll notice that `copy_source` includes the source bucket name.